# Elements below the expandable list - not floating footer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

Is there any option to put elements below the expandable list, let me explain: I already implemented elements below the list, but they are behaving like footer - floating at the bottom of the screen.

But if i place elements below the list in xml, elements become hidden when any group is expanded.

at the moment my layout is behaving like this

http://shrani.si/f/2s/ba/ga2VKfi/lay2.jpg

but i want to be like this at the end of the list

http://shrani.si/f/42/4m/2GAcNu6T/lay3.jpg

My layout at the moment

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutListExer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/ExerciseELV"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutStatus"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeFooter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutListExer"

                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewBellowExercise"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="The following exercises will help you lose body weight"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textViewBellowExercise">


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonFaceit"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/green"
                            android:text="FaceIT!"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonChallenge"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/red"
                            android:text="Challenge"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your following property should change.
Instead of
    `android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutListExer"`

you should write 
`android:layout_below="@id/ExerciseELV"`

for the LinearLayout with `android:id="@+id/relativeFooter"`

This will make the bottom layout appear below the listview

Comment: Your solution fixed my footer at the bottom of the screen, but that is not what i am trying to achieve. I want it to be bellow the list and when i expand 1 group item i want to push footer lower. At the moment expanded list is pushed bellow footer, when expanded.

Comment: You said "At this moment expanded list is pushed bellow footer, when expanded". A small correction. The list is never pushed below anything. A list view is designed to show minimal items on the front but when scrolled, it shows the other hidden items. Your group4 contents have crossed the limit of the display hence it is hidden behind the scenes. the same code will work perfectly for a tablet(provided the list contents stay the same). But for mobile you need to modify your layout approach.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, your solution works fine, but it was not what i was looking for, i ended up using "addfooterview" method, which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android so i'm sorry for any "stupid" questions i may be asking.

I ended up using addfooterview method which works great.

You need to separate footer layout in its own xml and then inflate it and add it to expandable listview.

```
    View footer=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_footer,null);
    elv.addFooterView(footer);
```